# Julia: Avoid memory allocation due to nested function calls in for loop

Tags: performance, memory, julia

I've seen multiple questions addressing memory allocation in Julia in general, however none of these examples helped me. 
I provide a minimal example that shall illustrate my problem. I implemented a finite volume solver that computes the solution of an advection equation. Long story short here the (self contained) code:

```
function dummyexample()
    nx = 100
    Δx = 1.0/nx
    x = range(Δx/2.0, length=nx, step=Δx) 
    ρ = sin.(2π*x)
    for i=1:floor(1.0/Δx / 0.5)
        shu_osher_step!(ρ)      # This part is executed several times
    end
    println(sum(Δx*abs.(ρ .- sin.(2π*x))))
end

function shu_osher_step!(ρ::AbstractArray)
    ρ₁ = euler_step(ρ)                         # array allocation
    ρ₂ = 3.0/4.0*ρ .+ 1.0/4.0*euler_step(ρ₁)   # array allocation
    ρ .= 1.0/3.0*ρ .+ 2.0/3.0*euler_step(ρ₂)   # array allocation 
end

function euler_step(ρ::AbstractArray)
    return ρ .+ 0.5*rhs(ρ) 
end

function rhs(ρ::AbstractArray)
    ρₗ  = circshift(ρ,+1)                  # array allocation
    ρᵣ  = circshift(ρ,-1)                  # array allocation
    Δρₗ = ρ.-ρₗ                            # array allocation
    Δρᵣ = ρᵣ .-ρ                           # array allocation
    vᵣ  = ρ .+ 1.0/2.0 .* H(Δρₗ,Δρᵣ)       # array allocation
    return  -(vᵣ .- circshift(vᵣ,+1))      # array allocation
end

function H(Δρₗ::AbstractArray,Δρᵣ::AbstractArray)
    σ = Δρₗ ./ Δρᵣ
    σ̃ = max.(abs.(σ),1e-12) .* (2.0 .* (σ .>= 0.0) .- 1.0)
    for i=1:100
        if isnan(σ̃[i])
            σ̃[i] = 1e-12
        end
    end
    return Δρₗ .* (2.0/3.0*(1.0 ./ σ̃) .+ 1.0/3.0)
end
```

My problem is, that deep down in the call tree the function `rhs` allocates several arrays in every iteration of the most upper time loop. These arrays are temporary and I do not like the fact that they have to be reallocated every iteration. Here the output from `@time`:

```
julia> include("dummyexample.jl");

julia> @time dummyexample()
8.780349744014917e-5       # <- just to check that the error is almost zero
  0.362833 seconds (627.38 k allocations: 39.275 MiB, 1.95% gc time)
```

Now in the real code, there is actually a struct `p` passed down the whole calltree that contains attributes which I hardcoded here (basically every of the explicitly stated numbers would be referenced by `p.n`, etc.)
I could probably also pass down preallocated arrays like but that seems to get messy and I would have to change that every  time I want to do extra computations. 
Global arrays are discouraged in the Julia documentation but wouldn't that do the trick here? Are there any other obvious things I am missing? I am considering Julia 1.0.

Comment: Are you using `--track-allocation` https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/profile/#Memory-allocation-analysis-1 ? I ran your code and the `.mem` file shows no allocation in rhs other than the return array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing down preallocated arrays, as you say in the last paragraph, is exactly the right thing in this kind of situation.  Additional to that, I would devectorize the code into a manual loop containing a stencil and more indexing math instead of `circshift`.

Applying both ideas results in the following:

```
function dummyexample()
    nx = 100
    Δx = 1.0 / nx
    steps = 2 ÷ Δx

    x = range(Δx ÷ 2, length = nx, step = Δx)
    ρ = sin.(2π .* x)

    run!(ρ, steps)
    println(sum(@. Δx * abs(ρ - sin(2π * x))))
end

function run!(ρ, steps)
    ρ₁, ρ₂, v = similar(ρ), similar(ρ), similar(ρ)

    for i = 1:steps
        shu_osher_step!(ρ₁, ρ₂, v, ρ)
    end

    return ρ
end

function shu_osher_step!(ρ₁, ρ₂, v, ρ)
    euler_step!(ρ₁, v, ρ)
    ρ₂ .= 3.0/4.0 .* ρ .+ 1.0/4.0 .* euler_step!(ρ₂, v, ρ₁)
    ρ .= 1.0/3.0 .* ρ .+ 2.0/3.0 .* euler_step!(ρ, v, ρ₂)
end

function euler_step!(ρₒ, v, ρ)
    cycle(i) = mod(i - 1, length(ρ)) + 1

    # two steps of calculating v fused into one -- could be replaced by 
    # an extra loop for v.
    for I in 1:2:size(ρ, 1)
        v[I] = rhs(ρ[cycle(I-1)], ρ[I], ρ[cycle(I+1)])
        v[cycle(I+1)] = rhs(ρ[cycle(I)], ρ[I+1], ρ[cycle(I+2)])
        ρₒ[I] += 0.5 * (v[cycle(I+1)] - v[I])
    end

    return ρₒ
end

function rhs(ρₗ, ρᵢ, ρᵣ)
    Δρₗ = ρᵢ - ρₗ
    Δρᵣ = ρᵣ - ρᵢ
    return ρᵢ + 1/2 * H(Δρₗ, Δρᵣ)
end

function H(Δρₗ, Δρᵣ)
    σ = Δρₗ / Δρᵣ
    σ̃ = max(abs(σ), 1e-12) * (2.0 * (σ >= 0.0) - 1.0)
    isnan(σ̃) && (σ̃ = 1e-12)
    return Δρₗ * (2.0 / 3.0 * (1.0 / σ̃) + 1.0 / 3.0)
end
```

The above might still contain some logic errors due to my lack of domain knowledge (`dummyexample()` prints `0.02984422033942575`), but you see the pattern.  And it [benchmarks](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) well:

```
julia> @benchmark run!($ρ, $steps)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  699.13 KiB
  allocs estimate:  799
  --------------
  minimum time:     3.024 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      3.164 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        3.760 ms (1.69% GC)
  maximum time:     57.105 ms (94.41% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          1327
  evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: You have missed adding dots several places that will affect the amount of allocation. It might be useful to use the `@.` macro to avoid this.